# Can use aggregate functions with join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, grouping, aggregate-functions

- table projects : pid(pk), name ...
- table categories : pid(pk), project(project's pid), parent(other category's pid) ...
- table counts : project(project's pid), category(category's pid), count ...

I used this query before

```
SELECT
categories.*, projects.pid, projects.name, parent_category.*
FROM categories
INNER JOIN projects ON projects.pid = categories.project
LEFT JOIN categories AS parent_category ON parent_category.pid = categories.parent
```

and it worked well

This time we need SUM, COUNT data. So i added "counts" table and made this query.

```
SELECT
categories.*, projects.pid, projects.name, SUM(counts.count), COUNT(counts.count),
parent_category.*, SUM(parent_category_count.count), COUNT(parent_category_count.count)
FROM categories
INNER JOIN projects ON projects.pid = categories.project
LEFT JOIN counts ON counts.category = categories.pid
LEFT JOIN categories AS parent_category ON parent_category.pid = categories.parent
LEFT JOIN counts AS parent_category_count ON parent_category_count.category = categories.pid
```

Then I get

> ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot be nested

What can I do? Does this query basically make sense? Or should I split it?

Comment: you are missing `group by`.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table.

Comment: Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add  a proper GROUP BY clause  (in your case should be categories.pid  )

```
    SELECT
    categories.*
    , projects.pid
    , projects.name
    , SUM(counts.count)
    , COUNT(counts.count)
    , parent_category.*
    , SUM(parent_category_count.count)
    , COUNT(parent_category_count.count)
    FROM categories
    INNER JOIN projects ON projects.pid = categories.project
    LEFT JOIN counts ON counts.category = categories.pid
    LEFT JOIN categories AS parent_category ON parent_category.pid = categories.parent
    LEFT JOIN counts AS parent_category_count ON parent_category_count.category = categories.pid
    GROUP BY categories.pid
```

or as in your comment

```
    SELECT
    categories.*
    , projects.pid
    , projects.name
    , SUM(counts.count)
    , COUNT(counts.count)
    , parent_category.*
    , SUM(parent_category_count.count)
    , COUNT(parent_category_count.count)
    FROM categories
    INNER JOIN projects ON projects.pid = categories.project
    LEFT JOIN counts ON counts.category = categories.pid
    LEFT JOIN categories AS parent_category ON parent_category.pid = categories.parent
    LEFT JOIN counts AS parent_category_count ON parent_category_count.category = categories.pid
    GROUP BY categories.pid, projects.pid, parent_category.pid
```

Comment: Thanks! in my case it was Group by categories.pid, projects.pid, parent_category.pid